# Extract data from pdf form (or other Base format) to import to Libre Base database?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

I created a form in Libre Base, exported that form as a pdf, and will give that form to others. How can I extract the data from the completed forms and import that data back into the original database in Libre Base? Each form should create a completely new record, it does not append data to a record.

- How can I extract data from a completed pdf form (or other format) that I created in Libre Base and gave to others and very simply import the data from form #1 to record #1 of the original database in Libre Base?

Thanks.

Comment: see https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Working_with_Forms and https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Creating_a_database_form

Comment: @Rinzwind: Thanks! Unfortunately, the part I cannot do is extracting data from completed form for easy import into original Libre Base database.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy solution for this. Generally, `pdftk` is able to extract the form data out of a PDF form to a `fdf` file. But AFAIK there's no tool to import that data into LO Base. You will have to manually convert the fdf to csv, for example, so LO Base can access the data.